# How to make a class work as string for printf_s / sprintf_s?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I'm trying to make a class, let's say *MyClass*, work under the following condition:

```
MyClass name = "everyone";   // Assigns "everyone" into a local string variable.
printf_s("Hello %s!", name); // Should output "Hello everyone!" without the quotes.
```

I've tried overloading **operator const char*()** as well as **operator char*()** but neither seem to do the trick.

Comment: Could you supply the code for MyClass with the operators code.

Comment: `printf` is not typesafe, there is no magic in the world that can make this work without an explicit conversion. Something like `string`'s `c_str()` function would be a good solution, though. Why would you even want to support `printf`??

Answer (score 9):

If you overload it with `operator const char*`, you can explicitly cast it:

```
MyClass name = "everyone";
printf_s("Hello %s!", (const char*)name);
// prints "Hello everyone!"
```

And then it will behave properly. It doesn't work implicitly becase `printf` can take any type of parameter after the first one, so the compiler has no idea what to try to cast it to.

This assumes, of course, that `operator const char*` of your class returns the C-style string `everyone`.

As Tomalak Geret'kal noted in the comments, making your class implicitly castable to `const char*` could cause a lot of problems because it can cast itself without you knowing/wanting it to.

As Kerrek SB also pointed out, it's probably not worth making your class compatible with `printf`, since this is C++ after all. It would be better style to write an `operator<<` overload for `ostream&`s:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& rhs, const MyClass& c) {
    rhs << c.name; // assuming the argument to the constructor
                   // is stored in the member variable name

    return rhs;
}

MyClass name = "everyone";
cout << "Hello " << name << '!';

// prints "Hello everyone!"
```

Comment: +1 for factual accuracy, though it may also be worth nothing that attempting to make any class able to implicitly convert its instances to `char const*` is only going to lead to tears. There's a reason that `std::string` doesn't!

Comment: Another `operator<<` that only works with narrow streams. :-[

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "detect" the intention of being converted to a char const* when being passed into an ellipsis (...). Your object will just be put on the stack and you'll probably crash. This is different than if your object is passed in to a function that explicitly takes a `char const*`, in which case an implicit conversion operator can be triggered.

I would recommend going the same route as the standard library and rely as little as possible on implicit conversions. Instead, use a `c_str()` member or something.